# Why the specflow tags are not working with scenarios?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, gherkin

I Created few scenarios under the feature file Patient Search with 2 different tags on individual scenarios
as mentioned below.

```
@PatientSearch
@Fucntional
Scenario: Patient Search-Choose a Favorite Search
    Given I have no Portal page open

@InpatientSearch
@Functional
Scenario: Inpatient Search - Search the patient with the
```

I cant see those 2 scenarios in Test runner as separate tags.

[image]

Help needed!!! thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Just copy and paste, then click the code icon in the question editor.

Comment: @GregBurghardt : thank you :-)

Comment: I do not see those two scenarios at all in the test runner. How are you grouping tests in Test Explorer? Are you filtering tests?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: thanks for the response i actually cropped the image its missing the one of the tests in the test explorer .

Comment: thanks for mentioning the filter i actually not used any i was choosed the option Show Test Hirerachy . Now i changed the tests by adding filter Group By traits and it worked fine. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add the filter as GROUP BY TRAITS and it worked as expected with the tags i mentioned.

[image: Group By]

[image: Grouped By traits]